# Using ajax result in on( "tabsbeforeactivate") function fails

Tags: jquery, ajax

I try to use a ajax result for a true/false return in a function, but it doesn't work. I have read all about the stuff [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) so i built the following code:

```
$( "#toolbox-tabs" ).on( "tabsbeforeactivate", function( event, ui ) {
   validateSession().done(function(r){
     if (r.session)
        return true;
     else
        return false;
   });
});

function validateSession() {
   return $.ajax({
    url: check.php,
    data: {
        session_check : true
    },
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json'
  });
}
```

check.php is a simple print json_encode(array("session" => true/false));
The problem is that even if r.session is false, the on.function always returns true. Any help would be appreciated!

Kind regards,
Matty

Answer (score 0):

might be your calling function in wrong way try this..,

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
  beforeActivate: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

Try this in IF..

```
if(r.session == true){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: same, it always returns true (or, to be more specific, the tab is shown, even if r.session is false)

Comment: sadly still the same result as before

Comment: what you have got in `r`. try checking in `console.log(r);` post result here.

Comment: depends on the session. When the user is not logged in, I have
Object { session=false} in Log, but the Tab is showing, so the function get true as return

Comment: is this print on your console??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96891/discussion-between-ajay-makwana-and-matty82).